# Do you own the right to publish someone's work after you pay them?

Tags: legal

Let's say I ask someone to make a 3d model of a monster, can I then publish his work on a modding website? Is there any other thing I need to be aware of? Do I have to put his name to credit him for the model, or not? I am just wondering, because I am thinking of getting the help of some freelancers.

Answer (score 8):

Unless your contract **specifically states** that you own **all rights** or the right to resell/redistribute the work... then **NO** you do **not** have the right to resell or redistribute anything under *any* circumstance.

If you do not have rights, then adding a "credit" is meaningless. However, a contract *can* stipulate that reselling or distributing is permissible if a credit/attribution is included. Creative Commons licensing often has this stipulation.

In short.... **It depends upon what the contract agreement for the work states**. Without a formal contract or by default, the *artist* owns all work he/she creates and you have *no rights* to resell/distribute anything (at least under United States laws - laws may be different in other locations).